# remove private key from X509Certificate2

Tags: c#, x509certificate2

I'm using the following method to export a certificate chain that contains two `X509Certificate2` objects: a certificate and the Certificate Authority that issued it:

```
public void ExportCertificateChain(X509Certificate2 cert, X509Certificate2 ca, string outPath, string password)
{
    X509Certificate2Collection collection = new X509Certificate2Collection();
    collection.Add(cert); //certificate with private key

    //remove private key from CA, because don't want it to be usable for signing, we just want to install it to validate the first certificate
    ca.PrivateKey = null; //This throws an "Access Denied" exception!!!
    collection.Add(ca);

    var raw = collection.Export(X509ContentType.Pfx, password);
    File.WriteAllBytes(outPath, raw);                        
}
```

the problem, as the comment in the code already tells, is that nulling the private key throws an exception that tells me "access denied"

How do I properly remove the private key from a `X509Certificate2` object (or, alternatively, how do I get it from the store WITHOUT the private key in the first place?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, I found a workaround while waiting for answers, which is this:

```
ca = new X509Certificate2(ca.Export(X509ContentType.Cert));
```

basically, this does an on-the-fly export of the CA certificate without the private key, and then immediately re-builds it back to a new `X509Certificate2` object.

Still leaving this question open for a bit, in case someone else points out a more "proper" solution. But this seems to work well.

Comment: Yes, it is the easiest (and reliable) way to accomplish your goal.

Comment: I usually use `new X509Certificate2(ca.RawData)`.  Same thing, but shorter.

Comment: @bartonjs it looks like RawData does not contain the private key ... I was unable to find documentation that states that this is expected/guaranteed behavior. Given that the Export API seems to better express this behavior I prefer the added ~20 characters. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I created the following function to clean up all the private key files one of our applications was leaving around. I thought others might find it useful.

```
  `private static void RemoveWindowsKeyFiles(X509Certificate2 cert)
    {
        if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows))
        {
            try
            {
                CngKey? cngKey = null;

                using (RSA? rsa = cert.GetRSAPrivateKey())
                {
                    if (rsa is RSACng rsaCng)
                    {
                        cngKey = rsaCng.Key;
                        foreach (X509Extension extension in cert.Extensions)
                        {
                            if (extension.Oid?.FriendlyName == "Subject Key Identifier")
                            {
                                X509SubjectKeyIdentifierExtension ext = (X509SubjectKeyIdentifierExtension)extension;
                                var systemCertificateKeyPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "\\Microsoft\\SystemCertificates\\My\\Keys\\" + ext.SubjectKeyIdentifier;
                                File.Delete(systemCertificateKeyPath);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if (cngKey != null)
                    {
                        var uniqueKeyPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "\\Microsoft\\Crypto\\Keys\\" + cngKey.UniqueName;
                        File.Delete(uniqueKeyPath);
                        cngKey = null!;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (CryptographicException)
            {
            }
        }
    }`
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).